# WPF DataGrid: Bind columns to different levels of the source collection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

How to bind a WPF DataGrid to get the following result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wne0.png

Note the desired +/- buttons on the left.
The DataGrid's ItemsSource is bound to an IEnumerable of Document.

The question is how to define the columns so they bind to the second and third level of objects and get the expand/collapse buttons.
I don't want to have a second and a third grids for Group and Field items, defined in the RowDetail of the parent.
The goal is to have a single DataGrid, one row of columns' headers and the ability to expand the child elements of the current row (if any).

```
public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FieldType FieldType { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind to the property i.e. {Binding Document.Group.Name}.

Note that all your classes must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  All your properties should raise PropertyChanged as is widely documented.
Your collections should be ObservableCollections.

Comment: I can't see how your suggestion will work. However, I tried several variations of your idea with no success. Code sample is for hierarchy illustration only. I do use ObservableCollections and PropertyChanged aware properties.

Comment: Well why dont you post the code you are actually using. Then you will get responses that are better suited to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The only trick i found here is to use nested datagrids with template columns and no headers for smooth view.

In Code:

```
DocumentGrid.ItemsSource = YourDocument;
```

The XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DocumentGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Document"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Group       Field      FieldType  IsRequired">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <DataGrid x:Name="dgInner" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  GridLinesVisibility="None" BorderThickness="0" HeadersVisibility="None">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>

              <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Field">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dgInnerInner" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None"  BorderThickness="0" HeadersVisibility="None">

                      <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FieldType" Binding="{Binding FieldType}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IsRequired" Binding="{Binding IsRequired}"/>
                      </DataGrid.Columns>

                    </DataGrid>
                  </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

          </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

  </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

EDIT
If you want +- buttons to collapse details you should use DataGrid's RowDetailsTemplate like described [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/)